# Match a substring and delete array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array `["C09111718/1/165", "J04111732/1/241.5", "T03111746/1/200"]`, I want to delete the element which starts with `"C09111718"`
How can I achieve this using Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well @Maulen's answer is awesome. I would just like you to know of [**Array#some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and how you can achieve your solution with this.

Just for fun :)

```js
var array = ["C09111718/1/165", "J04111732/1/241.5", "T03111746/1/200"];
var match = "C09111718";

function deleteIfMatches(array, match){
 array.some((ele)=>{
ele.indexOf(match) >= 0 ? array.splice(array.indexOf(ele),1): null
 });
 console.log(array)
}
deleteIfMatches(array, match);
```

Comment: How is this a better answer? `ele.indexOf(match) >= 0` returns true even if C09111718 isn't at the beginning of the string. Moreover `array.indexOf(ele)` isn't needed since `Array#some` takes the index as the second parameter. Not to say a forEach would have been enough.

Comment: It doesn’t make any sense at all to use `some` in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` function to exclude any element starting with `C09111718`

**NOTE:** this method will create a new array.

ES6:

```js
var arr = ["C09111718/1/165", "J04111732/1/241.5", "T03111746/1/200"];
var newArr = arr.filter(str => !str.startsWith("C09111718"));
console.log(newArr);
```

ES5:

```js
var arr = ["C09111718/1/165", "J04111732/1/241.5", "T03111746/1/200"];
var newArr = arr.filter(function(str) {
  return !str.startsWith("C09111718");
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have answer but still just a suggestion. **if you have string to be searched in between**. also later you can utilize power of regex. :D

```js
 var arr = ["C09111718/1/165","J04111732/1/241.5","J04111732/C09111718/241.5","C09111718/1/165","C09111718/1/165","T03111746/1/200","C09111718/1/165"];
    
    arr = arr.filter(function(item){
     return item.search('C09111718') == -1;
    });
    
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Happy to help... :D